# Change the DateTimeOriginal Exif Data based on the first 8 digits of file name (Using exiftool)

Tags: image, filenames, exif, batch-rename, exiftool

I have a folder with jpeg files with names of the format `YYMMDD <Sequence>.jpg` Eg. 20120424 10.jpg

I am trying to change the *datetimeorignal* EXIF data based on filename ignoring the sequence number. ie. based on the first 8 digits, ignoring anything after the "space".

Tried exiftool with the below commands

`exiftool "-datetimeoriginal<filename" .`

Also I tried

`exiftool "-datetimeoriginal<${filename;$_=substr($_,0,8)} 00:00" .`

which didn't work.

and it works fine for names with a sequence number that can be converted in to an "hour". ie 1-23 but fails for something like `20120424 99.jpg` where it cannot be an hour.

**How can I change the *datetimeorignal* only based on the first 8 digits?**

Comment: In what way did the second option not work, as that works correctly here.  If you're not on Windows, swap single/double quotes. Are you using some program other than exiftool to see if it works?  If so, then it's a case of [exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3).  Your other program is displaying some other tag in the file.

Comment: Thanks, @stargeek. It was the single/double-quotes. I was using the Windows OS with its "terminal" app (Not the command prompt). When I change it to single quotes, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer highlighted by @stargeek in his comment above, the reason for this to not work as expected was the double-quotes. When I changed them to single quotes it started working perfectly.